# How to use log base 2 with GEKKO (Python)

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem with GEKKO using python, I'm trying to develop some mathematical function with log and sqrt and I figure out that I should use gekko operator instead of using numpy or math function. I wanted to know how to implement log base 2 instead of log or log10 using gekko.

```
gk = GEKKO()
gk.log(...) # work
gk.sqrt(...) # work
gk.log2(...) # does not work!
```

**Error** :

```
AttributeError: 'GEKKO' object has no attribute 'log2'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead you can change the log base using the rule:

```
log2(x) = gk.log(x)/gk.log(2)
```

You can't expect for it to have all of the log bases implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `log2` function in Gekko, especially if you need to use it multiple times throughout your model.

```py
def glog2(x):
    return gk.log(x)/np.log(2)
```

Below is a complete script that demonstrates the use of the new `log2` function and shows the agreement with the Numpy `log2` function.

[image: log2 Gekko function]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

# compare with numpy
xnp = np.logspace(-1,4,100)
ynp = np.log2(xnp)

gk = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = gk.Param(xnp)
y,z = gk.Array(gk.Var,2)

# define a new log2 function
def glog2(x):
    return gk.log(x)/np.log(2) 

gk.Equation(y==glog2(x))
gk.options.IMODE=2; gk.solve(disp=False)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.semilogx(xnp,ynp,'b-',lw=4,label=r'$y=\log_2(x)$ Numpy')
plt.semilogx(x.value,y.value,'r--',lw=2,label=r'$y=\log_2(x)$ Gekko')
plt.legend(); plt.xlabel('x'); plt.ylabel('y'); plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

Comment: Note that `gk.log()` is the natural log while `gl.log10()` is log_10.